# Will changing MySQL innodb_file_format and large_prefix cause any issues for other websites?

Tags: mysql, moodle

### Explanation:

Trying to install [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) and the installation process says I need to make the following changes in MySQL config (for full unicode support):

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = barracuda

SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = 'on'

SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

This is a shared hosting with cPanel, every other requirement is set/installed.

### Question:

There are many other websites on this server using MySQL with the old settings and my question is if I run the commands above and change `innodb_file_format to "Barracuda"` (currently it is Antelope) and `innodb_large_prefix to "on"` will this cause **any possible issues** for other websites?

If yes, how do I avoid them? can I set this setting for a single database only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These changes have no effect until you recreate the tables. Only new tables pick up the changes. You don't have to explicitly drop the tables though. IIRC a `ALTER TABLE foo FORCE;` also does the job. This might take a while, though. If you don't want to have a downtime, you can use `pt-online-schema-change` for example (from the percona-tools).

Whatever is reading from or writing to your database tables, doesn't care at all about these changes.

No, you can not set these settings for a single database only. It's for all databases on your server.

Comment: Thank you, so no need to worry about other (older) websites on this server

Comment: Hi @T.Rex, yes, no need to worry. I'm not really sure about that `alter table foo force;` thing, though. In the manual it only says `You can also use ALTER TABLE tbl_name FORCE to perform a “null” alter operation that rebuilds the table.` and I've used it for other things, but in this case I'm not sure. Have a try and look if a separate `.ibd` file is created for the table in the data directory. If not, either rebuild the table on your own with `mysqldump schema table | mysql schema` or look for an operation that rebuilds the table in the manual page of `online ddl` (you can google that). ...

Comment: We didn't use that `alter table foo force;` command as we don't want to rebuild older tables, just wanted them unchanged and unharmed :D Thanks again <3